# Click on link with custom angular directive

Tags: php, angularjs, selenium, behat, mink

I have a question :

```
<ul _ngcontent-c4="">
   <li _ngcontent-c4="" class="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
       <a _ngcontent-c4=""><span _ngcontent-c4="" class="letter">a</span>
                YES
           <span _ngcontent-c4="" class="tick"></span>
       </a>
        </li>
   <li _ngcontent-c4="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" class="checked">
            <a _ngcontent-c4="">
                <span _ngcontent-c4="" class="letter">b</span>
                NO
                <span _ngcontent-c4="" class="tick"></span>
            </a>
        </li><li _ngcontent-c4="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
            <a _ngcontent-c4="">
                <span _ngcontent-c4="" class="letter">c</span>
                N.C.
                <span _ngcontent-c4="" class="tick"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The idea is to click on the link from a-c, I don't know how to do that in angular. 
I tried somethink like :

```
$this->selectOption("_ngcontent-c4", "YES"); but not work.
```

Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: There is neither any `a-c` tag nor any `a-c` text. What is your exact testing step? Can you update the exact HTML DOM unaltered?

Comment: I want to choose for example the response "YES"

Comment: Is this a dropdown? Update DOM.